# Android - How to display a image of a body with some parts in a way that does not break the layout on different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, androidsvg

There's a website callled [musclewiki](https://musclewiki.com/) that allow users to click on some muscle of the body.
I'd like to know how one could implement a similar thing on Android (MDC, not Compose).

I see that the website uses SVG, but I could make images just like the ones on the website and put they on the display if it would be a better approach, but I'm not sure how to make it work for every screen size.